# Keycode detection on AZERTY vs. QWERTY

Tags: javascript, keycode, qwerty, azerty-keyboard

How can I in JavaScript detect the typing of a question mark on AZERTY keyboard ?
On QWERTY keyboard a question mark produces the code 191,
but on AZERTY it seems to produce code 188 (comma on QWERTY).
Or should I distinguish between both keyboards in JavaScript, but how ?

Comment: You could spy on the key pressed down when typing certain characters. Like QWERTY it would be the `Shift` and the `/` key. But I guess only `Shift` would be visible. But I don't know of any way you could certainly tell which layout is used using JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

The fastest solution I can think of is to compare the key with the actual question mark, so something like this would be a good solution.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.key && event.key === '?') {
        // your code goes here
    }
}, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect the *character* being typed, use `KeyboardEvent.key`, not `KeyboardEvent.code` -- the `key` property will contain either the character that was typed (like `"?"`), or a string like `"Shift"` or `"ArrowUp"` for special keys. The location of the key on the keyboard won't affect the result.

```js
$("#f").on("keydown", function(ev) {
  $(this).val(ev.key);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="f" autocomplete="off">
```